# Soldiers use all kinds of technologies to combat nowadays. "They" used to fight with swords and spears in ancient times. - do we use "they"?

Tags: meaning, pronouns

**Example 1**

> American people are creative and focus on technology. But **they** used to heavily rely on farming and getting food from livestock.

Even if American people now and American people in the past are two different people, can we still use the pronoun "they"? and why?

**Example 2**

> Soldiers use all kinds of technologies to combat nowadays. **They** used to fight with swords and spears in ancient times.

Even if soldiers now and soldiers in the past are two different people, can we still use the pronoun "they" to refer to soldiers? and why?

Comment: **Soldiers use new technologies IN combat** or **....to combat their enemies**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, even though it refers to different people, this is a normal way, and the simplest way, to express this in English.

You can think of this as grouping both the past and present members of the group into one combined group, referred to in both sentences.

But more generally, it's ambiguous, and resolved by context if necessary, if a noun phrase refers to the actual one(s) or the selection process. It could mean either. I'm not finding the right words to describe this, so let's use an example:

> New soldiers today wear this uniform.
> Twenty years ago, they wore that other uniform.
>
> **VS**
>
> Twenty years ago, they wore diapers.

It's valid for "they" to mean either group of people: the people who are new soldiers today, or soldiers who are new in whatever time period.